# Focus loaded element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, focus

I want to replace a html element with jQuery's `load` method and want to focus an input element within the loaded elements with the class `.focus`. It is possible that there is more than one element with the class `.focus`, so it is important to select within the loaded element.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
  paragraphToBeReplaced.load(
    "/some/url", 
    function(event) { event.data.contents(".focus").focus(); }
  );
```

How can I set the focus to a loaded element? I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the load callback `this` is the element that new content is being loaded into. Using find() can search within this element for your class

```
paragraphToBeReplaced.load( "/some/url",    function() { 
         $(this).find(".focus").focus();
});
```

Comment: both ansers are essentially identical...  other answer uses find() within jQuery core to do same thing

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have a reference to the element into which you load the new content, you could use it again as a context:

```
paragraphToBeReplaced.load("/some/url", function(event) { 
    $(".focus", paragraphToBeReplaced).focus(); 
});
```

This should work, since the callback function is executed after the HTML returned by the URL has been inserted into the element.