# Focus element loaded by jQuery $.get(...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading a html snippet, insert it after a certain element and want to focus an input field with the class `.focus`. There could be more than one element with this class. [Similar code with `load(...)` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658075/focus-loaded-element-with-jquery).

```
  var item = $(this).closest(".something");
  $.get(
    url, 
    function(data) { 
      item.after(data);
      $(data).find(".focus").focus(); /* everything works except this line */
    }
  );
```

The relevant part of the loaded html:

```
<input type="text" class="focus" value="" name="email"/>
```

It looks like the element to be focussed is found (in the debugger), but it doesn't get the focus. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You probably want to use an id to focus your element. Otherwise, if there's more than one object with the .focus class and the other element(s) happen to be above your newly added element, they'll get the focus first. Also, try setting the focus outside of your `$.get()` statement.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. How can he focus element not created yet...? Can't be outside the `get` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item.after(data)` parses `data` into a set of DOM elements and puts them in your document.

`$(data)` then parses `data` into *another* set of DOM elements, which are never displayed.

You want

```
$(data).insertAfter(item).find(".focus").focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `data` is **not** in the DOM.

Try this:

```
  var item = $(this).closest(".something");
  $.get(
    url, 
    function(data) { 
      var $data = $(data);
      item.after($data);
      $data.find(".focus").focus(); /* everything works except this line */
      //or you can do: $(".focus", $data).focus();
    }
  );
```

Comment: `data` is in the dom. `$(data)` is not... as @SLaks answered.

Comment: Thank you, it works. What is the reason for `var $data = $(data);`?

Comment: @deamon. I think this way it refers to the same element, not creating new one what you use `$(data)` later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
item.next().find(".focus").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `item.next().find('.focus').focus()`. In the Ajax callback, `data` isn't a jQuery object but a string of HTML; calling `item.after()` makes jQuery create DOM nodes from the HTML but they're not linked to your `data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not calling `focus()` on the element which is added into the dom.

Try this.

```
var item = $(this).closest(".something");
  $.get(
    url, 
    function(data) { 
      item.after(data);
      item.nextAll(".focus").focus(); /* everything works except this line */
    }
  );
```

Comment: I think it won't work if .focus is inside item next sibling. nextAll is going to parse the siblings for .focus and not gonna traverse inside.

Comment: @SKS. how it be a sibling if he's adding data to it? must be a child of it.